# "ten times the wizard you are" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

> "I - so what if I did?" said Harry.
>
> "So, Dirk Cresswell is **ten times the wizard you are**," said Mr Weasley quietly, as the lift sank ever lower. "And if he survives Azkaban, you'll have to answer to him, not to mention his wife, his sons and his friends -"
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

What's "ten times the wizard you are" supposed to mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say

> A is ten times the wizard B is

you are essentially saying A is 10 times better than B in wizardry. In this context, Weasley is telling Harry that Cresswell is 10 times better than him [i.e., Harry].

I don't know the specifics, but it could mean that Cresswell's knowledge of wizardry, mastery over spells, and strength are all better than Harry's by 10 times.

From Cambridge: "times" is

> "used to show the difference in amount of two things, by multiplying one of them by the stated number"
>
> *This work is ten times better than the last piece you did.*